# How do I configure SSH on OS X?

Tags: macos, ssh, passwords, rsa

I'm trying to SSH from one Mac running OS X 10.6 to another. Seems to work fine via a password, but I can't get it to use a RSA key instead. Where is the ssh configuration file on OS X and what is the command to reload SSH?

**Update**

What I'm asking is how to configured advanced options. For example, on Ubuntu there is a ssh config file at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and if you do something like change the port or disable password authentication for a particular user (`PasswordAuthentication no`) you need to run `/etc/init.d/ssh reload` to reload the config. I didn't see that file on MacOs, so was just wondering where it was.

I am aware of the `~/.ssh`, `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and `~/.ssh/config` config files

Comment: By ssh configuration file, do you mean `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, the same file as on any platform?

Comment: And why do you want to reload SSH? Doesn't it suffice to update the `authorized_keys` file for the user account you want to log in as? Please describe the problem you're facing in more detail.

Comment: On Ubuntu there is a ssh config file at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and if you do something like change the port or disable password authentication for a particular user (`PasswordAuthentication no`) you need to run `/etc/init.d/ssh reload` to reload the config. I didn't see that file on OS X, so was just wondering where it was. I am aware of the `~/.ssh` `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and ``~/.ssh/config`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The SSHD configuration is stored in

```
/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

To stop and start SSHD:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd
```

Comment: Not sure if this is just because of how my machine is setup or not, but as of OS X Mavericks the sshd service I needed to specify in `launchctl` is `org.openbsd.ssh-agent`

Comment: I think you mean `/private/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `/private/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. Don't forget the ssh directory.

Comment: my settings: `alias restartsshd='sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.ssh-agent; sudo launchctl start com.openssh.ssh-agent;'` Get the service name by using `launchctl list | grep openssh`

Comment: As of Catalina, you no longer need to restart the sshd service after a configuration change! At least for when setting `PasswordAuthentication no`, it appears to take effect as soon as the file is saved.  Nice!

Answer (score 6):

I found out that in **macOS Monterey** (12.0), if you just disable `PasswordAuthentication`, it will still ask for a password (in the `keyboard-interactive` mode). To fully disable it, you have to set two options in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

And then restart SSH server with these commands:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

Or going to System Preferences -> Sharing and unchecking + checking "Remote Login".

Comment: I'm on Monterey and I've triple-checked these settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but I can still login with a password as the admin user of the machine. Any way to disable that and only allow logins from `authorized_keys`?

Answer (score 3):

You can restart SSH somewhere in the sharing dialogs, but you don't have to.  According to the [man page on apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sshd.8.html) keys go to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

Answer (score 3):

In OS X El Capitan 10.11, sshd_config is in /private/etc/ssh/sshd_config (same as /etc/ssh/sshd_config)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in newer OS X releases it is not enough to enable "Remote login" in System Preferences > Sharing to allow SSH connections to your Mac if the firewall is running.

Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options. You will see that "Remote login" is listed on the top and incoming connections are allowed. Contrary to expectations this is not sufficient. You have to add another program called `/usr/libexec/sshd-keygen-wrapper` as well (locate its directory with [Shift-Cmd-G]), using the [+] button and then set "Allow incoming connections" for it. Now you'll be able to SSH into your machine.